# Crystal Reports Display String Formula Error

Tags: vb.net, formula, crystal-reports-2008

I have an application which is running over hundred of system , I am facing an error in formula statement and only the best and optimal solution to change in Stored Procedure rather change in Report DLL .
Below i m attaching the screen shots , If any body suggest the best solution.

[image: The Error]

[image: Data]

[image: Formula Code]

When **Gross** < 0 then this error occures.

any body suggest the solution

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because the string you are converting to number doesn't have any numeric value as string but it contains string characters...

You are again converting `Number` to `String` after converting to number... why this multiple conversions.. instead use string value directly..

If you still want to do the same way then suggested approach is to check first with `IsNumeric`  and then convert to number.

Main thing to consider is what does the variable `String` contains if `Gross<0`

Comment: Can it be fixed in data that I am providing, I don't want to change in Report Designer because of its mass distribution.

Comment: yes provide a astring value that is of numeric type with no characters

Comment: "0.00" is not Numeric? rather Double?

Comment: remove `.00` and print only `0`

Comment: The Column Tax is Decimal.. I Have set it 0,1 or any amount if its equivalent to 0.00 but when i select it again fetches to its Type. can you suggest me how to fetch so it show decimal value > 0 and 0 in case of 0.00?

Comment: Create a local variable and using if condition set that varable to 0 if it is 0.0 and use that in formula